# Cohomology Leray-Serre spectral sequence in case fiber is not connected?

Tags: algebraic-topology, spectral-sequences

Consider a fibration $F \to E \to B $, where $B $ is path connected. My question is can we use the cohomology Leray-Serre spectral sequence in case fiber is not connected? For example, when fiber is disjoint union of two spaces? In this case, does there exist a spectral sequence $E^{**}_r$ converge as an algebra to $H^*(E;R)$, with $$ E^{p,q}_2\cong H^p(B;\mathcal H^q(F;R)),$$
the cohomology of the space $B$ with local coefficient in the cohomology of the fiber.

Thank you so much in advance.

Comment: When you identify the $E_2$ page you find you are using cohomology with local coefficients. This is all that changes.

Comment: May and Ponto give a construction of the LSSS without the assumption that $F$ is connected in *More Concise Algebraic Topology*. I believe that the only real difficulty is identifying the edge homomorphisms as usual. You'll also find that many of the requirements for related results (say comparison results) are more difficult to verify.